# Parameter value not displaying in PHP page using JasperReports

Tags: php, mysql, jasper-reports

I created a report using *iReport* and displaying in a PHP page. My problem is when I create a parameter and assign it a value, it displays in the preview of *iReport* but does not display in my PHP page. How can I solve this?

I am sorry, I did not include my code. I write my PHP code, but stackoverflow shows some alignment errors.

Comment: I hope , ireport is making jasperxml for you, what lib u are using to integrate it in php ?

Comment: PhpJasperLibrary is used.it contains two files tcpdf,PHPJasperXML.inc.php and i include both files in my php code

Comment: did u pass the query parameter this way $PHPJasperXML->arrayParameter=array("parameter1"=>1); if not then please update your code to question so that we can check that?

Comment: <?php
//Import the PhpJasperLibrary
include_once('PhpJasperLibrary/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
include_once("PhpJasperLibrary/PHPJasperXML.inc.php");
//database connection details
$server="localhost";
$db="live";
$user="root";
$pass="mysqlword";
$version="0.8b";
$pgport=5432;

Comment: $pchartfolder="./class/pchart2";
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
$xml =  simplexml_load_file("parameters.jrxml");//parameters.jrxml my jrxml file created using Ireport
$PHPJasperXML = new PHPJasperXML();
$PHPJasperXML->xml_dismantle($xml);
$PHPJasperXML->transferDBtoArray($server,$user,$pass,$db);
$PHPJasperXML->outpage("I");    //page output method I:standard output  D:Download file
?>

Comment: I am sorry. I dont know how to add code to this. I am new in stackover flow

Answer (score 0):

Your Code
with added parameter,

Before xml  dismantle and after creating $phpJasperXml , pass the parameter array

```
    //Import the PhpJasperLibrary
 include_once('PhpJasperLibrary/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
 include_once("PhpJasperLibrary/PHPJasperXML.inc.php");
 //database connection details
 $server="localhost";
 $db="live"; $user="root"; 
 $pass="mysqlword"; 
 $version="0.8b";
 $pgport=5432; 
 $pchartfolder="./class/pchart2";

 ini_set('display_errors', 0);
 $xml = simplexml_load_file("parameters.jrxml");//parameters.jrxml my jrxml file created using Ireport

 $PHPJasperXML = new PHPJasperXML(); 

 //$PHPJasperXML->debugsql=true; // to see the error and object

 $PHPJasperXML->arrayParameter=array("parameter1"=>1); // to pass the query parameter as array

 $PHPJasperXML->xml_dismantle($xml); 
 $PHPJasperXML->transferDBtoArray($server,$user,$pass,$db);
 $PHPJasperXML->outpage("I"); //page output method I:standard output D:Download file
```

Comment: Hai sir,thank you very much. But a problem it shows always 1 in the place of parameters.                                                  $PHPJasperXML->arrayParameter=array("parameter1"=>1);in this line change 1 into other it shows that value.Can you help???

Comment: array("parameter1"=>1), where parameter1 is parameter name and 1 is value, you can pass value like, $val =5; array("parameter1"=>$val);

Comment: Dear Sir, I created a parameter name parameter1 and its value in jrxml is $P{parameter1}.$PHPJasperXML->arrayParameter=array("parameter1"=>$P{parameter1}); but it show any parameter value.Is it correct??? Please help

Comment: all the things are correct except last line code.$PHPJasperXML->arrayParameter=array("parameter1"=>$P{parameter1})‌​; this is php , $P{parameter1} is in jrxml, to get the value of parameter1, in php you can not write that, you should provide some value from php, that paramter1 will have in jrxml, like when you send array("parameter1"=>1),this value in  php,  then jrxml will replace $P{parameter1} to 1. got !

Comment: Thank you sir, I understood my problem.But i did not get how to solve it and also how to convert the jrxml parameter to php variable?? Please suggest.